# How to get year of a specific date older than the current date?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to find out the date of the last April. I want to run my code from 1 April to the current date. So, if I run the report in Feb 2020 then the start date should be April 1, 2019.

How can I do this in Python? Right now, I am just getting the current year which is not the right approach since it will cause error as it will require the report to run from 1 April, 2020 to 5th Feb 2020 which doesn't make sense.

```
"REPORT_for_{}-04-01_{}.xlsx".format(datetime.today().strftime('%Y'),
                                     datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you won't get april from last year before april and april this year after april.

```py
today = datetime.today()

april_date = datetime(today.year, 4, 1)

if april_date > today:
   april_date = datetime(today.year -1, 4, 1)
```

This is a one liner for your report. It's ugly as hell and I would not recommend it. One liners are not always that good.

```py
"REPORT_for_{}-04-01_{}.xlsx".format(datetime.today().year-1 if datetime.today().month < 4 else datetime.today().year, datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Another option would be:

```
year = datetime.today().year-1 if datetime.today().month < 4 else datetime.today().year
"REPORT_for_{}-04-01_{}.xlsx".format(year, datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

or even better:

```
today =  datetime.today()
year = today.year-1 if today.month < 4 else today.year
"REPORT_for_{}-04-01_{}.xlsx".format(year, today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: this makes sense, but I want to do this in one line of code. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime.year`:

```
"REPORT_for_{}-04-01_{}.xlsx".format(datetime.today().year-1, datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
# Output: 'REPORT_for_2019-04-01_2020-02-05.xlsx'
```

Comment: This will give me the previous year. So if I ran my report on Dec 1 2019, then this code will give me April 1 2018.

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear. You can use NicoT's answer